# How to (best) use a SPI SD card with STM32F1 or STM32F4?

Tags: stm32, spi, stm32f4, sd, stm32f1

Below, is the SD card reader I would like to use. It's using SPI.

On an Arduino I got it to work (using SPI).

However, I want to test it on a STM32F103C8T6, and later use it in STM32F407VET6. However, I see both the F1 and F4 can use the FATFS file system, which I need, but only the F4 has the SDIO peripheral (the F1 has not).

But since it is an SPI SD reader, I don't think I will need SDIO anyway.
However, still I wonder how to control it. Should I find out myself what SPI commands I should sent or are there better ways? Or should I get an SD card reader without SPI?

For my project, the requirements regarding SD are pretty low. I want to read one file from it, from max. 128 KB, and I don't care much about the speed (within one second is good enough). Maybe later I want to write to it too (also no fast time restrictions).

What would be the easiest way to read from this type of SD card reader?

I would rather use CubeMX and System Workbench (Eclipse).

[image: SD card reader]

Comment: This is not a SD-Card reader with SPI Interface, but a breakout board from SD-Card to a pin header. SD-Cards have a SDIO and SPI interface as standard.

Comment: @Arsenal ... Thanks Arsenal, in this case I think SPI is good enough, especially if I can combine it with FATFS (I already asked for an example to filo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way if of course SPI. I am not sure if SPI protocol is the only one publicly available.

Software side - use FATFS, there is an STM32F100 demo code already.

Comment: Thanks ... I was unaware the SD card in itself uses already SPI. And FATFS seems indeed logical to use. Where can I find the demo code (STM32F100)?

Comment: In the stm32 directory of FatFS zipfile ;)

Comment: And where can I find the STM32F100 demo code? I don't see that, thus also no stm32 directory.

Comment: http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/ffsample.zip